# Using 2 side-by-side tables to display a long list of key-value pairs?

Tags: tables, info-visualisation, data-tables, data

I've a list with 20+ key-value pairs that I need to display in my app. The data is static and cannot be edited.

I'm using a table, currently it looks like this:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| keyA | valueA |
| keyB | valueB |
| keyC | valueC |
| keyD | valueD |
| keyE | valueE |
| ... | ... |

For more than 20 key-value pairs, this takes a lot of vertical space and wastes horizontal space.

I was thinking of putting 2 tables side-by-side, or a single table where every cell displays a key-value pair (instead of a column for keys, a column for values)

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| keyA: valueA | keyB: valueB |
| keyC: valueC | keyD: valueD |
| keyE: valueE | keyF: valueF |
| ... | ... |

Not sure if this is right? Is the data easily readable?

Answer (score 2):

I would stick to your original approach, where you have a column for the key and a column for the value, now I'm assuming that the user don't need the 20+ tuples at the same time. You always need to think on how to make information accessible to the user when they need it.

I would add a search field on he top of the table that allow the user to search for a given value/key and the table below can show only the relevant tuples like when you search for a contact at your phone address book.

Comment: Thing is, the data is displayed in a modal, and the data is only used as a reference. The user imports the data from another application, there is a modal where they can correct fields that haven't been imported correctly, and the reference data is displayed under the fields. I want to minimize scrolling, that's why I thought it would be better to have 2 columns

Comment: Got it, probably the only suggestion that I would made if you are going with two columns is try to be really explicit on how a key item looks vs a value item to avoid confusions, use font weights and/or colors